# Spanish keyboard doesn't work in US 18.04

Tags: keyboard-layout, language-support

I have installed the Spanish keyboard layout on 18.04 with a US GUI (because I'm learning Spanish, but don't know enough to set the whole system to Spanish yet).

The keyboard shows in the list, but selecting it has no effect at all: typing the key to the right of the L still gives me a semicolon not an n-tilde.

Also, using Tweaks I tried using the dead keys with the US keyboard, but the combination that should have produced n-tilde gave me n-macron instead.

I have installed the Spanish language support, and I have rebooted, but the behavior doesn't change.

Any ideas on why this would not be working?

Comment: Please don't mix multiple questions in one question. Let's concentrate on the Spanish keyboard layout. And, no, basically I have no idea. It should just work - with or without the Spanish language support. What's the output of this terminal command: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources`

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem. I've added my second lang. then removed the first language(English). Tested the keyboard and the second layout was working fine. Then added the first layout and it all went well.